# What could stop Basic Authentication credentials in URL to work?

Tags: git, http, nginx, gitlab

I have a self-hosted Gitlab Omnibus EE instance. To clone git projects I use https with username and password (or Access Tokens). If I use

`git clone https://username:password@myhost.tld/user/project.git`

I get a 401.

But if I exclude the username/password from the URL and supply them when prompted it works fine.

Username and access token are both alphanumerical in ASCII range. Nothing that should be escaped.

What could cause this? Is nginx mangling the URL somehow? Is git not making the correct hash for the HTTP header? Why would Basic Authentication work when prompted but not when supplied in URL?

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe you can pass creds to `https` like that (it's not SSH).

Git does allow you to set this in config: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Before you continue, please consider why you need the password in the config - does this run headless? In general, I would never condone having a password hanging around in config - it's a HUGE security hole. Git tokens are safer because you can lock them down, but again, not ideal. Also worth noting that if you ever change your password, all of this will break.

If this box is your's (and only your's), set up your SSH keys and add it to your GitHub account (preferred). If not, set up a Github token.

If you *really* want it to supply the password without a prompt (at completely your own risk):

```
   GIT_ASKPASS='echo "mypassword"'
```

Please be very aware:

- if you run this command, your password will end up in your Bash history, for anyone with access to your user area (or root access on the box) to see
- if you add it to the script, anyone with view access to the script now has your GitHub password

Comment: Yes, you can pass credentials before the URL in http(s). The client will read it and construct an `Authorization: Basic [hash of user/pass]` header.

Regarding security, this will be used in a short-lived docker container.